# Displaying POM version number in AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, maven

What's the most efficient way of displaying the version number contained in a POM file in my Angular App?

I have a REST application running on Tomcat.

I guess there are a couple of options

1. Have a REST service that just delivers the version number of the application
2. Create a text file during the mvn build and copy that into the web app, then read the file from the front end

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: What we do is just write a service which sends the {product version, environment , User name}. this is invoked on through app.module('app').config.

Answer (score 4):

The typical way of doing that is by adding a placeholder for the version in some file of your web-application and replacing that placeholder at compile time:

1. Add the placeholder `${project.version}` in a file of your choice under `src/main/webapp`.
2. Configure the `maven-war-plugin` like this:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.6</version>
       <configuration>
           <webResources>
               <resource>
                   <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                   <filtering>true</filtering>
               </resource>
           </webResources>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```

   This plugin will replace the placeholder `${project.version}` with the current Maven version at build time.
3. The rest of your application can now access the Maven version as if it were a simple hard-coded String.

Comment: Does this mean that if I, for instance, run the app in debug mode without ever having packaged the war, I won't have the version number displayed?

Comment: @Pram It depends on how your IDE is configured. Using an up-to-date Eclipse, m2e and m2e-wtp, it should work and the version number should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven replacer plugin to replace specific pattern in files (web pages) by version from pom during build. example:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>                    
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>      
                    <file>${warSourceDirectory}/index.html</file>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>%PROJECT_VERSION%</token>
                            <value>${project.version}</value>
                        </replacement>
                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```