# Get maven profile properties inside JSP/HTML script tag

Tags: java, maven, jsp, properties

I have a maven project where I tell to modify the resources that I want to customize depending on the profile specifiec profile. For example, I have a crm URL that I want to change when the profile is changed. The profile is defined as follow in pom.xml:

```
    <profile>
        <id>RELEASE</id>
        <properties>
            <config.crm.script>/js/crm-one-scripts</config.crm.script>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
```

So in ***application.properties*** I have the following property that have to be changed when I build with this profile:

```
application.crm.jspath = ${config.crm.script}
```

And now I would like to set that property in a script html tag in a JSP page as follow but it's replaced by nothing:

```
<script src="<c:url value="${application.crm.jspath}/crm-webservices.js" />"></script>
```

Is there something wrong with this approach ?

Comment: Are you filtering that JSP page? Can you show your POM?

Comment: What do you mean by filtering JSP pages ?

Comment: Take an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32560608/1743880) for configuration with the war plugin. Filtering means that Maven will replace your tokens at built-time.